# ASP.NET FileContentResult always 404 in production

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http-status-code-404, web-deployment

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 web app that's behaving strangely. There's an action that allows me to download a test file:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Download()
    {
        var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = "test_file.txt",
                Inline = false,
            };

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
        return File(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("HELLO THERE"), "text/plain");
    }
```

In debug mode it works no problem, I get a file download as expected ("test_file.txt", with contents "HELLO THERE").

When published, and deployed with IIS 6, a 404 error is always returned. Anyone know why the difference and how to fix it?

Comment: Do other actions work as expected? Your problem may be related to your configuration of IIS and your app rather than your code; for example, does the destination server support MVC applications?

Comment: Thanks for the response, you're exactly right, realized the problem last night. Will answer below!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was a combination of routing and IIS configuration. I had some parameters for the action, one of which contained a file extension. I had set up a route so that the parameters were in the format

```
    ../Download/[text].txt
```

instead of

```
    ../Download?[text].txt
```

IIS was reading this as trying to access a file on the file system. I removed the custom route and all was resolved.

Comment: This prompted me to discover my stupid hard-coded url in javascript, meaning no relative path for when put onto production. Thanks